# VS Code Notebook - Possible to customize color scheme?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using [Monokai Pro](https://monokai.pro/vscode) as the color scheme of my VS Code. However, a problem with this scheme is that the color for comments has terrible contrast and it is very difficult to read.

I have already added the following rule to my VS Code settings (JSON) so that comments will display in the `#a1a1a1` (brighter) color instead of the default `#727072` (darker) color:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai Pro]": { 
        "comments": "#a1a1a1",
    },
},
```

Just to demonstrate that this rule works, the comments in any file types other than `.ipynb` have the brighter `#a1a1a1` color instead of the default darker `#727072` color:

[image: Brighter comment color]

However, it seems like this rule is not applied on Jupyter Notebooks opened inside VS Code. When I open `.ipynb` files inside VS Code, the comments now have the default color of `#727072` (darker) and it seems like the above rule is not applied to Jupyter Notebooks:

[image: Comments in Notebook]

Therefore, I would like to ask is there a method that I can **customize the color of comments** in the code cells of Jupyter Notebook opened inside VS Code? Thanks a lot!